# Looking for a video of experiment with two snug-fitting glass tubes

Tags: entropy, education, experimental-technique

R. Penrose in his book "Cycles of Time: An Extraordinary New View of the Universe" describes the following experiment:

There are the two snug-fitting glass tubes and viscous liquid between them, with line of red dye. The internal tube has a handle. When an experimenter rotate a handle in one direction, the red dye disappears, so it becomes uniformly smudged along the whole surface of the slot between the two tubes. However, if one starts rotate the internal tube in the opposite direction, at some point the red line of dye appears again back.

(This is not a citation from the book, but I have retranslated the experiment description).

I am certainly sure that I had met this experiment description somewhere else, but don't remember when and where. Just recently reading the afore-mentioned book, I have decided to find a video of the demonstration of this experiment. But I can't!

My essential questioning is to help find this experiment demonstration somewhere.

P.S. One can google "snug-fitting glass tubes Roger Penrose" and could find this book on the google books. I am not sure that I can paste here pictures or the text directly from the book, because it is covered by the copyright law.

Comment: Here is a link to the relevant pages which I assume is legal? https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DjUgfVFtY6YC&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=penrose+tubes+viscous+liquids+dye&source=bl&ots=aS-OGhpwVb&sig=j6GGvJfWz81YT6S5WFTd0WnG3ZE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjg4df54N_ZAhVSyKQKHX0wABQQ6AEwA3oECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=penrose%20tubes%20viscous%20liquids%20dye&f=false

Comment: These links aren't always visible. Google shares randomly only part of the book. For instance I currently can't load these pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tubes do not need to be snug. There are several videos about reversible laminar flow. Here is one from New Scientist:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UpJ-kGII074

And a blog post: https://www.newscientist.com/blogs/nstv/2011/08/born-to-be-viral-how-to-unmix-a-mixed-fluid.html